# Нужна помощь составить запрос выборки данных MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Поясните как правильно сделать выборку данных в моем случае

Что нужно:

1. выбрать все товары кроме тех у которых указана группа учитывая сортировку по sort *(может и по другому нужно)*
2. Для товаров у которых есть **group**: 
   Объединить по имени группы у которых она одинаковая, сортировка по **sort**, quantity > 0 LIMIT 1
   такое объедение и сортировка по всем группам

После этого объединение с товарами из первого пункта и результат.

Результат должен быть такой:

```
Товар 1, Товар 2, Товар 3, Товар 6, Товар 7, Товар 9, Товар 10
```

(товары 4,5,8 не вошли в результат, были отсортированы)

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `name`, `group`, `quantity`, `sort`) VALUES
(1, 'Товар 1', '', '5', '0'),
(2, 'Товар 2', '', '0', '0'),
(3, 'Товар 3', 'top', '1', '1'),
(4, 'Товар 4', 'top', '0', '2'),
(5, 'Товар 5', 'top', '15', '3'),
(6, 'Товар 6', '', '2', '0'),
(7, 'Товар 7', '', '10', '0'),
(8, 'Товар 8', 'sale', '0', '0'),
(9, 'Товар 9', 'sale', '12', '0'),
(10, 'Товар 10', '', '0', '0');
```

Версия mysql 5.7.16-10

Comment: 1) Замените скрин на набор скриптов CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. 2) Требуемый результат давайте не "примерно", а строго для приведённых исходных данных. 3) *выбрать только 1 продукт, первый по списку у которого quantity > 0.* Списка тут нет. Порядка записей - тоже нет, пока не указана сортировка. Укажите, причём по ней каждая запись должна быть уникальна. 4) Укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Написал ниже (не знаю получили уведомление или нет, по этому пишу в ответ на комментарий тут)

Comment: Осталось указать версию MySQL...

Comment: Версия mysql 4.9.4

Comment: Это phpMyAdmin а mysql наверное 5.7.16-10

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE `group` 
                                                WHEN '' THEN RAND()
                                                        ELSE `group`
                                                        END
                                   ORDER BY sort, product_id DESC) rn
         FROM product )
SELECT product_id, name, `group`, quantity, sort
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY product_id;
```

Требуемая версия MySQL - 8+.

Сортировка по `product_id DESC` добавлена для обеспечения уникальности и для полного соответствия эталонному результату.

---

Решение для MySQL версии 5:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE `group` = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*
FROM product t1
JOIN ( SELECT MIN(product_id) product_id
       FROM product
       WHERE `group` != ''
         AND quantity > 0
       GROUP BY `group` ) t2 USING (product_id)
ORDER BY product_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3534d033cac4b1d08ee1c8bf55950862)

Comment: на хостнге стоит версия 4.9.4 ))

Comment: Это точно версия MySQL? именно её показывает `SELECT VERSION();`?

Comment: VERSION()
5.7.16-10-log

Comment: Во-о-от... но всё равно не восьмая... теперь только завтра, если никто не ответит раньше.

Comment: Спасибо что уделили внимание

Comment: @Сергей Добавлено решение для пятой версии.

Comment: @Akina, можете сказать, ваш код MySQL 8 как-то быстрее работает? Или какая необходимость использовать такую "конструкцию"?

Comment: @Node_pro Она проще. Логичнее. И менее нагрузочна - ибо в принципе не требует кэширования результата подзапроса.

Comment: @Akina,  я может устарел, но `WHEN '' THEN RAND()
                                                        ELSE `group`
                                                        END` выглядит не производительно. Не могли бы Вы посоветовать источник, где черпали знания

Comment: @Node_pro Что тут непроизводительного-то? это ж всё в памяти да кодом... по-моему, самый простой способ обеспечить "каждое пустое значение образует отдельную группу". *Не могли бы Вы посоветовать источник* Источник ЧЕГО ИМЕННО?

Comment: @Akina, не редко встречал критику в MySQL RAND(). Например при ORDER BY. Источник - что-то вроде продвинутый mysql 8 ;-)

Comment: @Node_pro Насчёт критики - согласен, сам против. Но в данном случае считаю его оправданным. `SYSDATE(6)` или `UUID_SHORT()` вряд ли быстрее. Во всяком случае определимо быстрее.

Comment: @Akina спасибо!